# How can I change a function to run in parallel with Rayon?

Tags: rust, rayon

I have a function, that gets an array, start index and end index. I want to return the largest element of this array. Sequentially it works fine. But I don't know how to convert it to work in prallel. So can you show me how to do it. I've been trying Rayon's for_each() but always got some errors. How would converted function look like?

```
pub fn search_max(array: &[f32], start: i32, end: i32)-> f32 {
    let mut maximum: f32 = A[p as usize];
    let iter: usize = start as usize + 1;
    for iter in iter..end as usize{
        if maximum < array[iter] {
            maximum = array[iter];
        }
    }   
    maximum
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've currently got what's called imperative code; it cannot be directly changed into parallel without going through a functional style:

```
pub fn search_max(array: &[f32], start: i32, end: i32) -> f32 {
    let sub_array: &[f32] = &array[start as usize..end as usize];
    *sub_array.iter().max().unwrap()
}
```

We use the [`max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max) method to get the maximum value produced by the iterator. This [does not work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc47db0f98ced8a5b5081e416dddff40) since `f32` cannot be guaranteed to order nicely. 
We'll use [`max_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by) instead with a closure:

```
pub fn search_max(array: &[f32], start: i32, end: i32) -> f32 {
    let sub_array: &[f32] = &array[start as usize..end as usize];

    *    // This results in &f32, so we must dereference it
    sub_array.iter() // Create the iterator over references to the items
    .max_by(
        |x, y| x.partial_cmp(y).unwrap() // https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#tymethod.partial_cmp
    ).unwrap() // There could possibly be no items! So we get an `Option<&f32>` instead.
}
```

For the most part, `rayon`'s [`ParallelIterator`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.2.1/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html) is a drop in replacement for a regular iterator, so anywhere we see `.iter` we change to `.par_iter`:

```
use rayon::prelude::*;

pub fn search_max(array: &[f32], start: i32, end: i32) -> f32 {
    let sub_array: &[f32] = &array[start as usize..end as usize];
    *sub_array.par_iter().max_by(|x, y| x.partial_cmp(y).unwrap()).unwrap()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69a0028bad60c016bce0c12ed5cd4fbd)

---

If you're looking for the most idiomatic version of this:

```
pub fn search_max(slice: &'_ [f32], start: usize, end: usize) -> f32 {
    *slice[start..end].par_iter().reduce(
        || &slice[start], // This is an iterator over &'_ f32
        |a, b| if a > b { a } else { b },
    )
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a986a7d0b846abf302ef22134adf7027)

Comment: For the "most idiomatic" version, you probably wouldn't pass `start` and `end` as parameters since the caller can always do `search_max (slice[start..end])` herself if she doesn't want to search the whole slice.

Comment: Or accept [`impl RangeBounds`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.RangeBounds.html)

Comment: @Jmb I wanted to preserve the caller side for the most part; personally I'd not have this function like so, as though parallelism seems a bit too much for a simple max/min implementation.